# Heat pump (AC Heater) start cooling once programmed temp is reached?

Tags: heating, heat-pump

My AMANA (and another McQuay unit) in wall AC/heat pump unit works fine on cold days. However, I noticed when the room temperature is higher than the programmed temperature the heater starts letting in cold air. Ideally I would like it to just switch off until the room temperature drops below the programmed number. Is there anything I can do to achieve this desired behavior?

My unit looks is [closed to this model](https://www.shop4air.com/amana-heat-pumps-ptac-unit-model-pth-r-410a/) but not exactly the same one

Comment: This is a thermostat control issue.  Either switch the thermostat mode from "Auto" to "Heat" or increase the deadband between the heating and cooling setpoints.

Comment: i only have heat, cool, and fan modes. it's in heat mode and still does this. Is there anywhere else that I can change this?

Comment: If it has only "heat" and "cool" then it should not be cooling in "heat" mode.  If the the fan is set to "on" instead of "auto," that can feel drafty in some cases.  With thermostat in "heat" and fan in "auto" there should be no air from the vents when the room temp > setpoint.   If there is, then you have a malfunction of some type (duct work issues, incorrect control wiring, fused fan relay, etc -- no way of telling without some trouble shooting).

Comment: It could be the unit going into defrost mode if it happens right after it completes heating. Is it running continuously until it reaches a set temperature, or just for a short period of time?

Comment: Just short period of time. When I initially turn it on, it starts heating, reaches a temperature, then I hear the click (which I presume the heating element turning off) and cold air comes in for a short amount of time. Then the unit turns off for a while. Then sometimes it comes back on with cold air and eventually works to heat the room. I am guessing this the internal mechanism of the unit. Going to run more tests: set the mode to heat, temp to 60 while the room temperature is 68. Ideally it should not start right?

Comment: If you have the owner's manual, you might find there is a fan delay setting causing the fan to run for a minute or two after the end of a heating cycle.  It might be possible to disable that.  Regarding startup, cold for awhile sounds like a typical heat pump in cold weather when not equipped with an indoor head pressure control.  You might check if a cold weather indoor head pressure control is available for your unit.  It's doubtful that is an aftermarket option.